# List visible sheets of multiple files into a master file

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new in VBA and I guess this is an easy one, but I can't solve it.

I have a `Masterfile.xlsm` which have a list of several `.xlsb` files and their respective folder path. What it has to do is go to each of the files, look all of it's visible sheets and list then in `Masterfile.xlsm`.

This is all I have so far, but it's not working properly.

```
Sub sheets_count()

Dim i As Long, n As Long
Dim FilePath As String
Dim iCell As String

Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Control").Activate
LastRow = Range("D2").End(xlDown).Row
intRowCount = LastRow
FilePath = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value

For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
Workbooks("Masterfile.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Control").Select
iCell = Cells(i, 4).Value
Workbooks.Open FileName:=FilePath & iCell
If Worksheets(i).Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
    i = i + 1
    Workbooks("Masterfile.xlsm").Activate
    Worksheets("shts_list").Cells(i, i) = iCell
    Worksheets("shts_list").Cells(i + 1, i) = Sheets(i).Name
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Where (i.e. which column) do you want the sheet names? Your code currently increases both row and column number for each sheet.

Comment: (1, 1) = 1st iCell name and the sheets list filling (2,1), (3,1) and so far..

Answer (score 0):

This should get you there - you may want to adjust the output layout:

```
Sub sheets_count()

    Dim i                     As Long
    Dim LastRow               As Long
    Dim FilePath              As String
    Dim sCell                 As String
    Dim rgOut                 As Excel.Range
    Dim wb                    As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wsControl             As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wsVis                 As Excel.Worksheet

    With Application
        .EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    ' start output in A2
    Set rgOut = Worksheets("shts_list").Range("A2")

    Set wsControl = Workbooks("Masterfile.xlsm").Sheets("Control")

    With wsControl

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

        FilePath = .Range("A2").Value
        If Right$(FilePath, 1) <> "\" Then FilePath = FilePath & "\"

        For i = 1 To LastRow

            sCell = .Cells(i, 4).Value

            With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilePath & sCell)
                rgOut.Value = sCell
                Set rgOut = rgOut.Offset(1)
                For Each wsVis In .Worksheets

                    If wsVis.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
                        rgOut.Value2 = wsVis.Name
                        Set rgOut = rgOut.Offset(1)
                    End If

                Next wsVis

                .Close False

            End With

        Next i

    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableCancelKey = xlInterrupt
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, It works like a charm! I have one more question: I don't know how exactly how to change the syntax in your loop, to adjust the output layout as I wanted: (1, 1) = 1st sCell and their sheets below. (1, 2) = 2nd sCell and their sheets below and so far.. Could you help me?

Comment: Almost there! Your last edit put all data on column A. What I want is A1 = 1st sCell and it's sheets in A2, A3,... B1 = 2st sCell, sheets in B2, B3,...

Comment: Before the `Next i` line, add: `Set rgOut = rgOut.Offset(, 1).EntireColumn.Cells(1)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry for being so annoying, but one more question: how do I set _read only_ and the _update links_ both false? The syntax (updatelinks:=0,readonly:=false) that I know doesn't work here.

Comment: It should do - what did you actually try?

Comment: `With Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FilePath & sCell), ReadOnly:=False, UpdateLinks:=0
ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever`

Comment: Close: `With Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FilePath & sCell ,  ReadOnly:=False, UpdateLinks:=0)`